# Install RVM part of a "UserData" script for an EC2 instance

Tags: bash, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, rvm

I've Base64 Encoded this Userdata script to be ran on initialization of a EC2 instance, but for some reason, it doesn't install RVM. I think it's do to a user issue, but i'm not sure.

I'm using the 12.10 default Ubuntu AMI.

```
#!/bin/bash 
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
sudo apt-get --yes update
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 7F0CEB10
deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen
sudo apt-get --yes --fix-missing install mongodb language-pack-en ruby-full build-essential openssl libreadline6 libreadline6-dev curl git-core zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev autoconf libc6-dev ncurses-dev automake libtool bison subversion pkg-config tcptrack
\curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
source ~/.profile
rvm autolibs 3
rvm requirements
#source ~/.profile
rvm install 2.0.0-p0
rvm --default use 2.0.0
gem update --system
gem i mechanize peach mongo rails aws-sdk bson_ext httparty
```

Comment: as what user is this script ran?

Comment: it's the initialization script for EC2 servers at first boot, I'm guessing root. The default login is ubuntu.

Comment: if the script is run by root you most likely will end up with "broken" installation in `/usr/local/rvm`

Comment: Having some issues as well with mine, add # user-data logging: https://alestic.com/2010/12/ec2-user-data-output/ 
**exec > >(tee /var/log/user-data.log|logger -t user-data -s 2>/dev/console) 2>&1**
at this line to the top of the script to get an output at /var/log/user-data.log